# Why can't I see my reviews?

Tags: support, recent-activity, review

On `profile > activity > reviews` I cannot see the reviews. I only see:

```
(nothing in this date range)
```

I think this message is quite inappropriate. Is there any way to see if my flag was accepted by peers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "reviews" tab in your profile lists the [**suggested edits**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) that you have reviewed and voted on (either to approve or reject the edit). Remember that you are only able to review suggested edits if you have full [edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) yourself (at least 2k rep). If not, you won't have anything listed in this tab.

In order to see your **flags** and find out which have been marked as valid or invalid, you need to click on the flag weight link in your profile, underneath the reputation counter:

[image: click the "flag weight" link underneath your reputation count in your profile]

That links you to [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/637367), which displays a summary of all the posts you've flagged, whether they were dismissed as valid or invalid, and what action (if any) was taken in response.

Comment: where do I list my edited posts ?

Comment: @Marcio:are you asking about,you want to see the list of posts edited by you,if yes you can see here profile > activity > revisions