# Is it wrong to say "Hi"

Tags: discussion, questions, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should 'Hi', 'thanks' and taglines and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Is it wrong to start my question with "HI" ? I can often see my question gets edited because of that, like [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92034/why-cant-i-see-my-reviews)

Comment: [Yes, yes it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-and-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).