# Account activity for reviews not updating when editing from reviews page

Tags: discussion, support, edits, edit-badges

I've noticed that my account activity page for 'reviews' has never changed from displaying:

> 0 Reviews
>
> You have no reviews

However when I go to the review page I'm told:

> You have edited a total of 16 posts (20% done).

Are my edits on the reviews page meant to only be listed under revisions? It seems like this is something worth displaying under 'reviews' also when the edit has been done via the revisions page.

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92034/why-cant-i-see-my-reviews

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reviews tab of your profile is for listing suggested edits that you've cast an approve or reject vote on, not posts that you've edited via `/review`.

Comment: Ah, I was mis-interpreting what was being displayed there. I was under the impression that posts were being displayed for review (flagged by some medium), not edits.

Comment: The review page is meant for general site health tasks (flagging, editing, voting, and the like), so the use of the word "reviews" for that particular profile tab is probably not the ideal choice since its more limited in scope.