# reviews tab is confusing

Tags: discussion, review, new-users

One of the things I really like about SO is the ability to help guide newbies under the "review" section.  However, my activity has a "reviews" tab (as explained in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92034/why-cant-i-see-my-reviews)), but that is for something completely different.  As far as I can tell, there's no way to see the stats for the reviews I've done with new users.  Can we use different terms to avoid confusion?

Comment: *"to see the stats for the reviews I've done with new users"* What do you mean by that?

Comment: Click on "review" on the top, between your name/rep/badges and "chat"

Comment: I would like to see the statistics from my activities under that section.